# Dynamic Parameter Function from another file with NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have confused about dynamic parameter function from another file, compare with normal function.
for example :

**1. Normal Function**

```
 function foo() {
    let arr=[]

    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      arr.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    console.log(arr.length)
 }

foo('aa','bb') ==> output 2 -> Correct
```

**2. Function from another file**

```
 *otherFunc.js

 module.exports = {
     running: () => {

         let arr = []

         for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            arr.push(arguments[i]);
         }
        console.log(arr.length)
    }
 }


 *tes.js

 var db = require('./otherfunc');
 db.running('aa','bb') ==> output 5 -> Not Correct
```

Why output two function is difference? how to solve this? thank you

Comment: `arguments` in an arrow function can't be accessed

Comment: Thank @NickParsons the problem solve... but why with arrow can't be accessed? function and arrow are similar right?

Comment: not sure for the exact reason why, but my best guess is that arrow functions and the spread syntax were both introduced in ES6. Using `(...args) =>` will allow you to access the arguments in an arrow function, so there is no need for `arguments` really